# Oracle 10g: Validating data using Type Constructor before insert / update

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, user-defined-types, object-relational-model

Is it possible to validate data before insert / update via type constructor? I have used typed object into a table. Need to know whether it is possible to get an error on application when I am inserting / updating data on the same...

Here is conceptual code...

```
-- Type Declaration:
create or replace type sampleType as object

(
    col1 number(2),
    col2 number(2),
    col3 number(2),
    constructor function sampleType return self as result
) not final;

-- Declaring constructor body:
create or replace type body sampleType as
    constructor function sampleType return self as result is
    inconsistant_data exception;
    pragma EXCEPTION_INIT(inconsistant_data, -660);
    BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line('Inside contrctor, before condition');
        if self.col1 + col2 != col3 then
            dbms_output.put_line('Raising exception');
            raise inconsistant_data;
        else
            dbms_output.put_line('Inside contrctor, returning...');
            return;
        end if;
        dbms_output.put_line('Inside contrctor, after condition');
        exception when inconsistant_data then
            raise_application_error(-20001, 'col3 should be equal to col1 + col2');
            raise;
    END;
end;

-- Using it in Table:
create table sampleTable (objSample sampleType);

-- Inserting values:
insert into sampleTable values (new sampleType(1, 1, 1));
```

The last statement here inserts a record. It should actually return an error. Need clarification and direction to show an application error and hault without inserting record.

Thanks in advance.